# JTable doesn't refresh after loading rows from file

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am using XStream to serialize/deserialize my objects to file. I have pretty basic JFrame window and some buttons on it, such as "Add", "Show table" and "Load from file". "Load" deserializes the XML file back to my `ArrayList<Person>` object. "Add" adds one Object to the ArrayList. The problem is, when i click "Add" and then press "Show table" it shows with one row, just as planned. But when i save it to file, restart the application and then load & show table - it shows nothing. When i click "Add" and again "Show table" still zero, even though `ArrayList.size()` returns int larger than 0.

The code bit, load function:

```
public void Load(){
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("database", Baza.class);
    xstream.alias("Person", Person.class);
    try{
        FileInputStream k = new FileInputStream("src/swing/project/database.xml");
        baza = (Baza)xstream.fromXML(k);
        baza.showAll();
        showPerson(baza.people.get(0));
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Loaded! " + baza.getSize());
}
```

The JScrollPane with table init function:

```
   public JScrollPane srodekTabela(){
       TableM modelik = new TableM(model.getBaza().people); //
       JTable tabela = new JTable(modelik); 

       tabela.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
       tabela.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
       tabela.setModel(modelik);
       JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabela);
       scroll.setOpaque(true);

       return scroll;
}
```

Then, when pressing "Show table" button, i just remove all other JLabels, revalidate & repaint the JScrollPane, which is added normally to JFrame.

```
    public void pokazTabele(){
        okno.remove(srodekDodaj);
        okno.remove(srodekZmien);
        okno.remove(srodekUsun);
        okno.remove(srodekTabela);                
        okno.add(srodekTabela, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        okno.revalidate();
        okno.repaint();
    }
```

I hope i gave all information. No idea why it doesn't work for pre-loaded ArrayList and works fine for ArrayList creating on-go.

Comment: How are the rows applied to the table model?  Do you fire any model changed events from the table model?  Have you read through [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular [Firing Data Change Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer do i need to use firing data changed events if every time i click "show table" i just remove and re-create the entire table? What do you mean, how rows are added? I add using ArrayList.add(Person p);

Comment: It would be efficient (and simpler) to simply update the model.  How does adding a new object to the `ArrayList` effect the model?

Comment: use CardLayout instead of remove something then add JTable, Swing JComponents are designated to be reusable, question in this form isn't answerable on this forum